# Assignment within lapply throws an error. [R]

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to add a new column to a bunch of datasets using lapply. But my code throws up an error.

The following is my code

```
z <- data.frame(a=rep("z",20))

datasets_list <- list(z,z,z,z)

lapply(datasets_list, function(k){k$New_Column <<- NA})
```

However running this returns the error `Error in k$New_Column <<- NA : object 'k' not found`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `transform` to create a new column

```
datasets_listN <- lapply(datasets_list, transform, New_Column = NA)
```

If we need to change the datasets in the global environment, use `list2env` (but it is better to keep the `data.frame`s in a `list`).  Suppose, the data.frame objects are 'df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4'

```
names(datasets_listN) <- paste0("df", 1:4)
list2env(datasets_listN, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

NOTE: Here the OP used the same dataset 'z' to show the example.